# Determine Values AND/OR Address of Values in CPU Cache

Tags: c++, c, windows, memory-management, cpu-cache

Is there a way to determine exactly what values, memory addresses, and/or other information currently resides in the CPU cache (L1, L2, etc.) - for current or all processes?

I've been doing quite a bit a reading which shows how to optimize programs to utilize the CPU cache more effectively. However, I'm looking for a way to truly determine if certain approaches are effective.

**Bottom line:** is it possible to be **100% certain** what does and does not make it into the CPU cache.

Searching for this topic returns several results on how to determine the cache size, but not contents.

*Edit:* To clarify some of the comments below: Since software would undoubtedly alter the cache, do CPU manufactures have a tool / hardware diagnostic system (built-in) which provides this functionality?

Comment: Interestingly, the system can't be observed without changing its state.

Comment: @SethCarnegie Obviously a good point. Now I'm curious if there is a built-in hardware diagnostic tool / subsystem that allows this.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I assume that chip makers have specialized hardware to inspect the cache state (for testing and diagnosing new chipsets).  But you cannot inspect the cache using software without altering it.

Comment: Curious about the downvote. I believe this meets all requirements for a question on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a relatively modern processor running Windows then take a look at
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization
and see if that might provide some of what you are looking for.

Comment: Although not 100% what I was looking for, it provided more value than the others.

Answer (score 3):

Without using specialized hardware, you cannot directly inspect what is in the CPU cache.  The act of running any software to inspect the CPU cache would alter the state of the cache.

The best approach I have found is simply to identify real hot spots in your application and benchmark alternative algorithms on hardware the code will run on in production (or on a range of likely hardware if you do not have control over the production environment).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Eric J.'s answer, I'll add that while I'm sure the big chip manufacturers do have such tools it's unlikely that such a "debug" facility would be made available to regular mortals like you and I, but even if it were, it wouldn't *really* be of much help.

Why? It's unlikely that you are having performance issues that you've traced to cache and which cannot be solved using the well-known and "common sense" techniques for maintaining high cache-hit ratios.

Have you *really* optimized all other hotspots in the code and poor cache behavior by the CPU is the problem? I very much doubt that.

Additionally, as food for thought: do you *really* want to optimize your program's behavior to only one or two particular CPUs? After all, caching algorithms change all the time, as do the parameters of the caches, sometimes dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize for one specific CPU cache size is usually in vain since this optimization will break when your assumptions about the CPU cache sizes are wrong when you execute on a different CPU.

But there is a way out there. You should optimize for certain access patterns to allow the CPU to easily predict what memory locations should be read next (the most obvious one is a linear increasing read). To be able to fully utilize a CPU you should read about [cache oblivious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache-oblivious_algorithm) algorithms where most of them follow a divide and conquer strategy where a problem is divided into sub parts to a certain extent until all memory accesses fit completly into the CPU cache.

It is also noteworthy to mention that you have a code and data cache which are separate. Herb Sutter has a nice [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L7zSU9HI-6I) online where he talks about the CPU internals in depth.

The [Visual Studio Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385772.aspx) can collect CPU counters dealing with memory and L2 counters. These options are available when you select instrumentation profiling.

Intel has also a [paper online which](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor-a-better-way-to-measure-cpu-utilization) talks in greater detail about these CPU counters and what the task manager of Windows and Linux do show you and how wrong it is for todays CPUs which do work internally asynchronous and parallel at many diffent levels. Unfortunatley there is no tool from intel to display this stuff directly. The only tool I do know is the VS profiler. Perhaps VTune has similar capabilities.

If you have gone this far to optimize your code you might look as well into GPU programming. You need at least a PHD to get your head around SIMD instructions, cache locality, ... to get perhaps a factor 5 over your original design. But by porting your algorithm to a GPU you get a factor 100 with much less effort ony a decent graphics card. NVidia GPUs which do support [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda-apps-flash-new.html#) (all today sold cards do support it) can be very nicely programmed in a C dialect. There are even wrapper for managed code (.NET) to take advantage of the full power of GPUs.

You can stay platform agnostic by using [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) but NVidia OpenCL support is very bad. The OpenCL drivers are at least 8 times slower than its CUDA counterpart.

Answer (score 1):

Almost everything you do will be in the cache at the moment when you use it, unless you are reading memory that has been configured as "uncacheable" - typically, that's frame buffer memory of your graphics card. The other way to "not hit the cache" is to use specific load and store instructions that are "non-temporal". Everything else is read into the L1 cache before it reaches the target registers inside the CPU itself.

For nearly all cases, CPU's do have a fairly good system of knowing what to keep and what to throw away in the cache, and the cache is nearly always "full" - not necessarily of useful stuff, if, for example you are working your way through an enormous array, it will just contain a lot of "old array" [this is where the "non-temporal" memory operations come in handy, as they allow you to read and/or write data that won't be stored in the cache, since next time you get back to the same point, it won't be in the cache ANYWAYS].

And yes, processors usually have special registers [that can be accessed in kernel drivers] that can inspect the contents of the cache. But they are quite tricky to use without at the same time losing the content of the cache(s). And they are definitely not useful as "how much of array A is in the cache" type checking. They are specifically for "Hmm, it looks like cache-line 1234 is broken, I'd better read the cached data to see if it's really the value it should be" when processors aren't working as they should.

As DanS says, there are performance counters that you can read from suitable software [need to be in the kernel to use those registers too, so you need some sort of "driver" software for that]. In Linux, there's "perf". And AMD has a similar set of performance counters that can be used to find out, for example "how many cache misses have we had over this period of time" or "how many cache hits in L" have we had, etc.